# How to use xp cmd dir to find file?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

There is a file named `calender` in my pc, i forget where it is.
I want to get the position of it with the `dir` command or some other command ?

```
dir c:\   | find "calender"   
find: ‘calender’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?  looked at the help for the dir command?

Comment: What help? Software no longer comes with manuals these days, and using switches and help commands are not obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/s` switch to search all directories:

```
 dir \calendar /s
```

If the filename is not *exactly* `calendar`, then you can use `*` as a wildcard (a placeholder for other stuff):

To search for files that *start with* `calendar`:

```
dir \calendar* /s
```

To search for files that have `calendar` anywhere in the name:

```
dir \*calendar* /s
```

And so on.

Also to remove all the information that DIR shows about the directory, such as file times etc, just use `/b` as it will leave the full path and nothing else.